# How to prevent use from putting non valid value in the autocomplete field?

Tags: jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

How do I prevent a user from inserting a value that is not in the source of the autocomplete?

```
var items=  [
    { "label": "Account Administration" },
    { "label": "Applications"},
    { "label": "General Information" },
    { "label": "Hardware" },
    { "label": "Network" },
    { "label": "Operating System" },
    { "label": "Remote Connectivity" }
];
$(".autocomp").autocomplete({ source: items});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well while coming up with an example I figured it out.

```
$(".autocomp").blur( function(event){
    s = this.value.toUpperCase();
var r = "";
for(var i=0;i<items.length; i++)
{
    if(s===items[i].label.toUpperCase()){ r= items[i].label; break;}
}
this.value=r;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DAElectric/bSPN2/

But is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

I faced this problem by adding an hidden input text. Then on autocomplete's change i set the selected value to the hidden field. Something like this:

```
...
$(".autocomp").autocomplete
({
   source: items,
   change: function(){$('hidden_field').val(ui.item.label);}
});
```

that way ensures you the hidden field will contains just valid autosuggested values or nothing if any of them has been selected.

In addition you can test

```
$('hidden_field').val() == '';
```

on autocomplete blur and then allert the user